# Nautilus rather than Dolphin

Tags: nautilus, firefox, dolphin

When using Firefox. I prefer Nautilus rather than Dolphin.

Since 18.04, Firefox uses Dolphin.

How do I get Firefox to link to Nautilus ?

Comment: Could you explain your question in more detail? In particular, what do you mean by "Firefox uses Dolphin"? Only Kubuntu comes with Dolphin; it does not provide Nautilus unless you install it yourself. What is your desktop environment? Have you installed more than one desktop environment? How many file managers have you installed? As it stands, your question is unclear.

Comment: Thanks DK for your questions and sorry to waste your time. I thought I had straight Ubuntu. But I think I had installed Konqeror (spelling?) and that brought in Dolphin. I prefer Nautilius and it is installed. But Firefox started Dolphin when I clicked on a downloaded file.  I have now removed Dolphin  and all is well again.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had straight Ubuntu. But I think I had installed Konqueror and that brought in Dolphin. 
I prefer Nautilus and it was installed. But Firefox started Dolphin when I clicked on a downloaded file.
The problem was solved by uninstalling Dolphin and all is well again.